# local variable referenced before assignment - Surely not this difficult

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, thonny

I'm trying to write a script to control movements of a camera. I'm writing it in Thonny on a Raspberry Pi. I receive the following error when trying to move the camera using the GUI buttons. I've asked around and tried troubleshooting the problem but no luck yet.

if anyone can help that'd be awesome.

I appreciate there are alternative workflows to this script but it's me combining an old script with a new GUI so I'd love to see if they could be merged. If not oh well, I'll implement the other workflow.

[Here is the error message from Thonny][1]

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime, sys, tty, termios

#defining root
root = Tk()
root.title('Operation Little Brother V02')


#setting GPIO board
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
servo1 = GPIO.PWM(3, 50)
GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
servo2 = GPIO.PWM(5, 50)


#setting servos to off 
servo1.start(0)
servo2.start(0)

#user input section
dummy = input('Initiate project. Press Enter')

#setting servos to 90degrees/startup sequence
print('launching start up sequence')
servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(6)
time.sleep(1)
servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
time.sleep(1)
print ('servo 1 test complete')
servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(6)
time.sleep(1)
servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
print ('servo 2 test complete')


# Defining Functions 
#x axis movement concept
def x_movement(x_dir):
    if x_axis <= limit_x_left and x_axis >= limit_x_right:
        x_axis = x_axis + x_dir
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(x_axis)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ('moved camera to position: ' +str(x_axis) + '/' +str(limit_x_left))
        return
    else:
        print ('limits reached')

#y axis movement concept
def y_movement(y_dir):
    if y_axis <= limit_y_down and y_axis >= limit_y_up:
        y_axis = y_axis + y_dir
        servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(y_axis)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        time.sleep(0.5)

        print('moved camera to position: ' +str(y_axis) + '/' +str(limit_y_up))
        return y_axis
    else:
        print ('limits reached')


#centre movement
def centre_movement():

    y_axis = 6
    servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(6)
    servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    x_axis = 6
    servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(6)
    servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('camera centered to position 6')
    return

#off sequence
def off():
    servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    servo2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    servo1.stop()
    servo2.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print('Whoopty fucking doo it\'s finished')
    exit()

#defining limits for x and y axis
limit_x_left = 9
limit_x_right = 3
limit_y_up = 3
limit_y_down = 9
x_axis = 6
y_axis = 6


#frame creation
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text = 'Welcome to Operation Little Brother', padx = 25, pady = 25, border = 5, fg = '#ffffff', bg = '#3e556b')


#button creation 
button1_left = Button(frame1, text = 'Left', padx = 20, pady = 20, fg = 'purple', bg = '#63778a', command = lambda: x_movement(1))
button2_right = Button(frame1, text = 'Right', padx = 20, pady = 20, fg = 'orange', bg = '#63778a', command = lambda: x_movement(-1))
button3_up = Button(frame1, text = 'Up', padx = 20, pady = 20, fg = 'green', command = lambda: y_movement(1))
button4_down = Button(frame1, text = 'Down', padx = 20, pady = 20, fg = 'blue', command = lambda: y_movement(-1))
button5_centre = Button(frame1, text = 'Centre', padx = 20, pady = 20, fg = 'black', command = lambda: centre_movement())
button6_start = Button(frame1, text = 'Start', padx = 10, pady = 10, fg = 'green')
button7_stop = Button(frame1, text = 'Stop', padx = 10, pady = 10, fg = 'red', command = lambda: off())

#positioning the frame
frame1.pack()

#button positioning
button1_left.grid(row = 3, column = 0,)
button2_right.grid(row = 3, column = 2,)
button3_up.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button4_down.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
button5_centre.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
button6_start.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button7_stop.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

#Text formatting
button1_left.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button2_right.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button3_up.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button4_down.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button5_centre.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button6_start.configure(font='Calibri 15')
button7_stop.configure(font='Calibri 15')

# Window Loop
root.mainloop()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIc0O.png
```

Comment: Erm, can you also give the stack trace of the error, or tell us  which variable or even show at which line the error occurs

Comment: Looking at your code you seem to not quite understand variable scope. Writing inside one of your functions `y_axis = 6` will not change the value of `y_axis` in the global scope it will only create and set it in the local scope. If you want tto change gloabl scope variables inside functions then you need to tell the function is global scope like `global y_axis` as the first line in the function. This is the cause errors

Comment: That said gloabl variables are normally discouraged, think about using a mutatble data structure like a dict which will hoold these values and name references instead

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've just added an image of the error message. So I'd appreciate you looking at that too. 
I'll also look into editing the function or even using a dictionary like you say. Thanks again

Comment: Don't add an image of text. Just include the text itself, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: I dont see any link, but like i say your issue is that your trying to change global variables in your local scope without telling your local scope your refering to the global variable